# Define Tame algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

How would you define a tame algebra such that undergraduate students could understand it easily? Do someone knows a good book that has a nice way to explain it?

Comment: Where have you come across this term?

Comment: The term of tame algebra?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Here is an example: http://www.m-hikari.com/ija/ija-2015/ija-1-4-2015/perezIJA1-4-2015.pdf (I can't find a book in pdf/djvu that contain the term).

Comment: Could you provide a reference that gives a definition?

Comment: The book "Rudimentos de mansedumbre y salvajismo en teoría de representaciones" is the book that I'm using to understand the definition, but is a bit complex.

Comment: Ahh, so you are the undergraduate student that needs to understand it? I had read the question as if you wanted a way to explain it to undergrad students.

Comment: I'm an undergraduate student trying to explain what is a tame algebra to undergraduate students.

Comment: But do you understand the definition well yourself, and you are looking for alternatives, or are you having trouble understanding the definition?

Comment: I understand the definition, but I want to know if there is an easy way to explain that definition, because the one I know contains a lot of things, so I don't know if someone has a one more short or easier.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Just to be clear, the term "tame" here is the same as "tame representation type"?

Comment: I think that yes.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/5895/what-are-tame-and-wild-hereditary-algebras has a neat summary.

Comment: Oh, thanks! It uses categories, but i think that I won't be able to give the definition without using  then.

Comment: The categorical language in play here can actually be pretty much avoided by reformulating things.

Comment: Perhaps the easiest thing is to say that roughly speaking, a tame algebra is one whose indecomposable modules can be classified, and then give the classification of modules over $\mathbb{C[x]}$ as an example of what is meant by classification.